# geting wifi signal level in c#

Tags: c#, wifi

I am trying to read the wifi signal continuously to see how wifi signal level is changing for an embedded system. I read several articles in SO on how to read wifi signal level in C# such as this :

[How often to poll wifi signal strength?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855206/how-often-to-poll-wifi-signal-strength?rq=1)

but when I am tring to do the same thing, I am always getting the same value. My code is as follow (simplified version):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string selectedSSDID = "BTWiFi";
        var client = new WlanClient();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            foreach (WlanClient.WlanInterface wlanIface in client.Interfaces)
            {
                Wlan.WlanBssEntry[] wlanBssEntries = wlanIface.GetNetworkBssList();

                foreach (Wlan.WlanBssEntry network in wlanBssEntries)
                {
                    var networkSSID = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(network.dot11Ssid.SSID, 0, (int)network.dot11Ssid.SSIDLength);

                    if (selectedSSDID == networkSSID)
                    {
                        Console.Out.WriteLine(network.rssi);
                    }
                }
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

when I ran this code, I would see that the signal level is always reported as one value and it doesn't change.

I used it against a embedded system which has a wifi and even when I put the device next to PC and when I moves to another room very far from the computer, if the application runs, it always report the same value, if I restart the application the value changes.

What is wrong with this code that it doesn't report correct value?

Comment: Can you try moving the code `var client = new WlanClient()` inside the `for` loop? The way it works, from sourcecode, is that it creates and looks for the network interfaces inside the constructor. Hence in your case you are creating instance only once and hence the information of instances is stored in memory and is not refreshed. So whenever you're restating the application it is again collecting information again since the constructor is called again.

Comment: @PratikGaikwad I can not move it to for loop as it generates error after some iteration.

Comment: well the error after some iteration is because `InterOp` objects are not released after use. But whatever number of iteration it worked for, did it change the value of signal? If so, then you will have to do small changes in original source code. Also did you try your original code on WiFi router and not Embedded device? Does it work there?

Comment: @PratikGaikwad Since the error happens very quickly, I can not see any changes. Am I right to belive that the interfaces which is fixed at the boot time, are representing wifi interfaces on the computer which is not changing?

Comment: For the error you can introduce delay of more than 1000 sec. No I would suggest you to test it on router first. Because the interfaces on computer record signals continue via polling of their own. You are just probing them to get the value.